# ¿Cómo se importa una clase que se encuentra en otro paquete? java

Tags: java

Estoy creando un juego de ajedrez en donde en la carpeta de fichas negras tengo una clase **peon**, y en otra carpeta llamada utileria se encuentra la clase **Circulo**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en utileria esta la clase circulo que es esta

```
package utileria;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Circulo extends JLabel{

    public Circulo(int tamanio){
        setBounds(0, 0, tamanio, tamanio);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 255));
        g.fillOval(350, 70, 50, 70);
    }
}
```

En la carpeta negros con la clase peon así intento llamar a la clase circulo

```
package negros;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import utileria.Circulo;
```

al compilar me sale este error: error: `package utileria does not exist import utileria.Circulo;`

también intente colocando la clase circulo dentro de el mismo paquete que peon pero tampoco me lo reconoce, no estoy del todo claro sobre la jerarquía, y no encuentro como solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0):

se tendría que ver la estructura de tu proyecto pero seguramente:

```
import com.example.nombrepackage.Circulo;
```

Ten en cuenta que si hay una carpeta intermedia también tendrías que añadirla a la ruta.

Espero que te sirva!